# With jQuery, is it possible to highlight a link with a background color that comes from an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, live, show

.live() handles only events, and I wish to traverse on the "live" elements to add a background color.

Is it possible with jQuery ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

.addClass can use for adding a class.

But you have to identify the links by id and apply it

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

http://api.jquery.com/add/

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: You don't have to identify by ID.  Any selector will do.

Comment: you mean class . he want to change the class so i didnt mention that :-)

Comment: 'But you have to identify the links by id and apply it' <- false.  You do not have to specify links by ID. Any selector will do.